# Minimize linear function with $\ell_1$ norm regularization and positive semidefinite constraint

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, positive-definite

I am running into the problem like this:

$\underset{\mathbf{X}\succ0}{\text{minimize  }} vec(\mathbf{A})^{\top}vec(\mathbf{X}) + \lambda ||\mathbf{X}||_1$

I am think about maybe one can minimize a similar linear function without consider the positive-definate property:

$\underset{X}{\text{minimize  }} A^{\top}X + \lambda ||X||_1$

where $A=vec(\mathbf{A})$ and $X=vec(\mathbf{X})$ for short.

Is there any way to solve the relaxed problem? how about the original one?

Comment: What do you mean, precisely, by $\|X\|_1$? The nuclear norm? The sum of the absolute values of the elements of $X$?

Comment: The objective function can be rewritten as $\operatorname{tr} (A^T X)$.

Comment: What does $$\underset{X}{\text{minimize  }} A^{\top}X + \lambda \|X\|_1$$even mean? You're adding a matrix and a scalar.

Comment: if you meant $\min_{x_k \ge 0} \sum_{k=1}^n x_k a_k + |x_k|$, the solution is obvious, component by component : $\min_{y \ge 0} y c + |y| = \min_{y} |y| (c + 1)$, if $c+1 < 0$   choose $y = +\infty$, otherwise $y = 0$

Comment: @MichaelGrant $||X||_1$ is the L1-norm of matrix.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $A^{\top}X$ is the inner product of vector $A$ and vector $X$

Comment: @cinvro No, the inner product is a scalar. The inner product is the trace of $A^T X$.

Comment: @cinvro, do you mean the *induced* L1 norm or the "vectorized" L1 norm? Again, there's a difference

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo is rightly objecting to the way you wrote the second model. $A^TX$ is not a scalar. $\langle A, X \rangle=\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(A^TX)=\mathop{\textrm{vec}}(A)^T\mathop{\textrm{vec}}(X)$ is.

Comment: @MichaelGrant sorry about the confusing, you are right, I am referring $A=vec(\mathbf{A})$ and $X = vec(\mathbf{X})$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I think it should be induced L1 norm.

Comment: I am interesting in this problem, can you tell me what background it come from?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean positive semi-definite (rather than positive definite) you should be able to apply many different convex optimization methods. For example, see the work on disciplined convex optimization by Stephen Boyd and Michael Grant and their solver CVX. If you mean strictly positive definite and can't relax this, best of luck to you, solving over open sets is wizardry (no different than requiring strict inequalities in other types of optimization.

Comment: Ha ha, you didn't have to edit it. :-)

Comment: @MichaelGrant No, I certainly did need to edit it! The downside of working with someone as well recognized as Boyd is sometimes you get less credit than you deserve.

Comment: There is no downside to working with Stephen Boyd :-)